# How can I wrap two jquery objects into one?

Tags: jquery

I have two functions.

### 1

```
function foo(elems){
   elems.each(function(){

   });
}
foo($('selector1,selector2')); // calling foo
```

### 2

```
function bar(elem1,elem2){
  // some logic 
}
bar($('selector1'),$('selector2)); // calling bar
```

However, now I need to use `foo()` inside `bar()`.

```
function bar(elem1,elem2){
   foo(?); // I'm stuck here. I want to pass both elem1 and elem2 as single jquery object
}
```

So I tried `$(elem1,elem2)` but it only includes `elem1`. So what should I do, so that I can pass `elem1` and `elem2` as a single jquery object which I'll iterate over in `foo()` by `.each()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [.add](http://api.jquery.com/add/#add-elements):

```
foo(elem1.add(elem2));
```

To combine the results of both selectors

Comment: +1 how could I forget `.add()`? Thanks will accept it as soon as I can :)

Comment: It's an easy one to forget when you're writing selectors all the time :-)

Comment: You see the irony here? My question is being upvoted, but I've reached 200 limit already lol

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jQuery "add" method, like this

```
$(elem1).add(elem2); //this now contains both elements
```